# Matlab errors sometimes on Boolean simplification

Tags: matlab, boolean-logic, symbolic-math, boolean-operations

I'm using Matlab for a project that involves working with symbolic arrays where each symbolic element is a Boolean. The problems comes when I try to simplify expressions.

Sometimes the function `simplify` returns this error:

> Error using mupadengine/feval (line 157)
>   MuPAD error: Error: The first argument must be a condition. 
> [simplify::simplifyCondition]

And other times, this error:

> Undefined function 'simplify' for input arguments of type 'logical'.

To give an example, here are two of my functions, the first one is a full-adder and the second performs the element-wise XOR of three vectors.

Full Adder:

```
function [carry, sum] = suma_sing (x,y,z)
    if (z == true) 
        z = 1;
    elseif (z == false)
        z = 0;
    end


    sum = (~x & ~y & z) | (~x & y & ~z) | (x & ~y & ~z) | (x & y & z);
    carry = (x & z) | (x & y) | (y & z);

    return
end
```

Because I'm working with a lot of elements, the formulas get complicated, so it is important for me to simplify them.

Example Code that WORKS:

```
symMsg = symbmatmake('x',1,5) %defines an array filled with sybolic 
variables x1, x2, x3, x4 and x5

symMsg2 = symMsg %defines an array filled with sybolic variables y1, y2, y3, y4 and y5

symMsg(end+1) = 1;
symMsg2(end+1) = 1;


symMsg(end+1:end+3)= 0; %% add some 1 and 0
symMsg2(end+1:end+3)= 1;

sum = sym(zeros(1,length(symMsg)));

auxc = 0;

 for i=1:length(symMsg)  

    [auxc,auxs] = suma_sing(symMsg(end+1-i), symMsg2(end+1-i),auxc);

    sum(end+1-i) = auxs;

 end

 display(sum)
 sum = simplify(sum);
 display(sum);
```

My main program is doing basically operations like this so I think probably my data types get changed (Although while debugging it still appear as sym)

Comment: Notice that there are some commented lines, I've tried them too but the same error keeps happening and simplify does not simplify the expressions at all :(

Comment: I assume by "crash" you mean throw an error? The Matlab application itself doesn't crash, right? These two things are very different. What `version` of Matlab are you using?

Comment: Yeah, with crash I meant error, specifically the ones in the description. I'm using Matlab R2014a

Comment: Thank you. Can you specify some example inputs (ideally as simple as possible) that generate these errors. Also, are those the full error messages? If not, please provide everything. Are both error still produce with the commented out version of `suma_sing`? If so, then you should probably clean up your question by removing the `xor_array3` and just providing the minimal code and inputs need to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I eliminated the "xor_array3" function for redundant. The exposed errors are the only and complete errors that I'm receiving. One input of 'suma_sing' might be 'suma_sing(x1 and x2, not 0 xor x1, 0)'

As you can notice the second parameter contains a 'not 0'. That should've been a 1 from the beginning. I have noticed that the errors show up when somehow the input is not treated as a logic or numbers.

Comment: What does `suma_sing(x1 and x2, not 0 xor x1, 0)` mean? That's not runnable code. What are `x1` and `x2`? Are they symbolic variables? Is "and" `&`, `&&`, or `sym/and`, etc.? Edit your question to provide a full runnable example with all variables and inputs defined and allocated so I and others can replicate this issue.

Comment: Yes the program works with symbolic variables that are meant to represent bits. suma_sing implements the logic for a full adder. If I insert manually symbolic variables to the 'suma_sing' function i get the error _Undefined function 'suma_sing' for input arguments of type 'sym'._ . However I don't get that error if I execute the whole code. So I can't give you an input that replicates my error :/

If it helps I have an array filled with symbolic objects, 0 and 1 and this functions is working with them. I think the problem is that sometimes I get results as 'not 0' as if 0 wasn't a number.

Comment: Let's stick with what your question about: you get specific errors in some cases. Edit your question with code that defines inputs and calls `suma_sing` such that you get the errors in question. I have a good idea what may be causing this, but I keep commenting to tell you to improve your question (not respond with more comments) so that your issue can be replicated, but you have not not done so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71629/discussion-between-albert-pasaret-and-horchler).

Comment: Did you find a solution? Here's a simple example that fails to simplify: syms x y z; simplify(x & xor(y, z))

Comment: I did not solve it as the project was abandoned but it would be really interesting to know the answer of this if you find it! :)